# Flask argument to use as dictionary key

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

How to use Flask parameter as a dictionary key, this is my code

```
@app.route('/test/<inp>')
def chossing(inp):
    dictio= {'ch1': 50000,   
            'ch2': 300000,  
            'ch3' : 150000}  
    lol = dictio[inp]
    return render_template('test.html', lol=lol, inp=inp)
```

and this is my html code

```
<select id='try'>
    <option value="">Pick one:</option>  
    <option value="{{ url_for ("chossing", inp = 'ch1') }}">first</option>  
    <option value="{{ url_for ("chossing", inp= 'ch2') }}">Second</option>  
    <option value="{{ url_for ("chossing", inp= 'ch3') }}">Third</option>
            </select>
```

how do i put value in select choice with value from my dictionary, using argument in flask

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is in the template. Try this.

```
@app.route('/test/<inp>')
def chossing(inp):
    dictio= {
        'ch1': 50000,   
        'ch2': 300000,  
        'ch3': 150000,
    }  
    return render_template('test.html', inp=inp, dictio=dictio)
```

```
<select id='try'>
    <option value="">Pick one:</option>
    {% for key, val in dictio.items() %}
    <option value="{{ url_for ("chossing", inp=key) }}" {% if key == inp %}selected{% endif %}>{{ val }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

For more details on how the templating engine works, you can have a look at [Jinja templates](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/)